# Named routes break RSpec Michael Hartl's Ruby on Rails Tutorial Chapter 5

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, railstutorial.org, rails-routing

I am working through Michael Hartl's Ruby on Rails utorial. Everything works great until named routes are tested in Chapter 5, and they all break Rspec. I have confirmed that they all work correctly in the browser, and in views.

For example, in a layout the following works:

```
<li><%= link_to "About", about_path %></li>
```

However, in my Rspec file the following produces an error

```
visit about_path
```

The error I'm getting is:

```
Failure/Error: visit about_path 
 NameError:
undefined local variable or method 'about_path' for #<Rspec::Core::ExampleGroup.....
```

Every single named route fails including root_path, so all of my specs fail.

EDIT:

Here is my `routes.rb`:

```
root to: 'static_pages#home'
match '/help', to:'static_pages#help'
match '/about', to: 'static_pages#about'
match '/contact', to: 'static_pages#contact'
```

Comment: can we see your routes.rb?

Comment: Sure - here's the section of my routes file. It works when navigating through the browser:  

`root to: 'static_pages#home'`  
`match '/help', to:'static_pages#help'`  
`match '/about', to: 'static_pages#about'`  
`match '/contact', to: 'static_pages#contact'`

Comment: Sorry, I can't seem to get the formatting right. Each of these is on a new line.

Comment: You should also include the relevant part of your RSpec file so we can see exactly where and how you used `visit about path`. Thanks.

Comment: Are you using spork? Try restarting the spork server.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19101618/rspec-not-finding-my-named-routes

Answer (score 0):

I think the error suggests that you have forgotten to include visit about_path in a before block that's why it's giving you an undefined variable or method. I think the answer is:

```
before { visit about_path }
```